SyncFuntion EJ2 PDF Viewer for loading and rendering ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC
I need assistance with fixing an issue in my ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC web application. I'm attempting to render a PDF from the server-side using PdfViewer. However, when I run the project, the PDF viewer keeps loading indefinitely. Could someone please help me troubleshoot this problem?
Image for more detail
This is the network:
enter image description here
I have read the documentation from 'https://ej2.syncfusion.com/aspnetcore/documentation/pdfviewer/getting-started-with-server-backed' and followed their instructions. I have created a PdfSampleController and used the 'serviceUrl' of 'ejs-pdfviewer' to call the 'Load' method from the controller like this:
Image for more detail
This is my controller:
public class jsonObjects
{
    public string document { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
    public string zoomFactor { get; set; }
    public string isFileName { get; set; }
    public string xCoordinate { get; set; }
    public string yCoordinate { get; set; }
    public string pageNumber { get; set; }
    public string documentId { get; set; }
    public string hashId { get; set; }
    public string sizeX { get; set; }
    public string sizeY { get; set; }
    public string startPage { get; set; }
    public string endPage { get; set; }
    public string stampAnnotations { get; set; }
    public string textMarkupAnnotations { get; set; }
    public string stickyNotesAnnotation { get; set; }
    public string shapeAnnotations { get; set; }
    public string measureShapeAnnotations { get; set; }
    public string action { get; set; }
    public string pageStartIndex { get; set; }
    public string pageEndIndex { get; set; }
    public string fileName { get; set; }
    public string elementId { get; set; }
    public string pdfAnnotation { get; set; }
    public string importPageList { get; set; }
    public string uniqueId { get; set; }
    public string data { get; set; }
    public string viewPortWidth { get; set; }
    public string viewPortHeight { get; set; }
    public string tilecount { get; set; }
    public bool isCompletePageSizeNotReceived { get; set; }
    public string freeTextAnnotation { get; set; }
    public string signatureData { get; set; }
    public string fieldsData { get; set; }
    public string FormDesigner { get; set; }
    public string inkSignatureData { get; set; }
    public bool hideEmptyDigitalSignatureFields { get; set; }
    public bool showDigitalSignatureAppearance { get; set; }
    public bool digitalSignaturePresent { get; set; }
    public string tileXCount { get; set; }
    public string tileYCount { get; set; }
    public string digitalSignaturePageList { get; set; }
    public string annotationCollection { get; set; }
    public string annotationsPageList { get; set; }
    public string formFieldsPageList { get; set; }
    public bool isAnnotationsExist { get; set; }
    public bool isFormFieldAnnotationsExist { get; set; }
    public string documentLiveCount { get; set; }
    public string annotationDataFormat { get; set; }
    public string importedData { get; set; }
}

public class PdfSampleController : Controller
{
    private IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;

    // Initialize the memory cache object   
    public IMemoryCache _cache;

    public PdfSampleController(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment, IMemoryCache cache)
    {
        _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
        _cache = cache;
    }

    public IActionResult Load([FromBody] jsonObjects responseData)
    {
        PdfRenderer pdfviewer = new PdfRenderer(_cache);
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        var jsonObject = JsonConverterstring(responseData);
        object jsonResult = new object();

        if (jsonObject != null && jsonObject.ContainsKey("document"))
        {
            if (bool.Parse(jsonObject["isFileName"]))
            {
                string documentPath = GetDocumentPath(jsonObject["document"]);

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(documentPath))
                {
                    byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(documentPath);
                    stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
                }
                else
                {
                    string fileName = jsonObject["document"].Split(new string[] { "://" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[0];

                    if (fileName == "http" || fileName == "https")
                    {
                        WebClient WebClient = new WebClient();
                        byte[] pdfDoc = WebClient.DownloadData(jsonObject["document"]);
                        stream = new MemoryStream(pdfDoc);
                    }
                    else
                        return this.Content(jsonObject["document"] + " is not found");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(jsonObject["document"]);
                stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
            }
        }

        jsonResult = pdfviewer.Load(stream, jsonObject);
        return Content(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonResult));
    }

    public Dictionary<string, string> JsonConverterstring(jsonObjects results)
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> resultObjects = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        resultObjects = results.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
            .ToDictionary(prop => prop.Name, prop => prop.GetValue(results, null));
        var emptyObjects = (from kv in resultObjects
                            where kv.Value != null
                            select kv).ToDictionary(kv => kv.Key, kv => kv.Value);
        Dictionary<string, string> jsonResult = emptyObjects.ToDictionary(k => k.Key, k => k.Value.ToString());
        return jsonResult;
    }

    // Post action for processing the PDF documents.
    public IActionResult RenderPdfPages([FromBody] jsonObjects responseData)
    {
        PdfRenderer pdfviewer = new PdfRenderer(_cache);
        var jsonObject = JsonConverterstring(responseData);
        object jsonResult = pdfviewer.GetPage(jsonObject);
        return Content(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonResult));
    }

    //Post action for unloading and disposing the PDF document resources
    public IActionResult Unload([FromBody] jsonObjects responseData)
    {
        PdfRenderer pdfviewer = new PdfRenderer(_cache);
        var jsonObject = JsonConverterstring(responseData);
        pdfviewer.ClearCache(jsonObject);
        return this.Content("Document cache is cleared");
    }

    //Post action for rendering the ThumbnailImages
    public IActionResult RenderThumbnailImages([FromBody] jsonObjects responseData)
    {
        PdfRenderer pdfviewer = new PdfRenderer(_cache);
        var jsonObject = JsonConverterstring(responseData);
        object result = pdfviewer.GetThumbnailImages(jsonObject);
        return Content(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result));
    }

    //Post action for processing the bookmarks from the PDF documents
    public IActionResult Bookmarks([FromBody] jsonObjects responseData)
    {
        PdfRenderer pdfviewer = new PdfRenderer(_cache);
        var jsonObject = JsonConverterstring(responseData);
        object jsonResult = pdfviewer.GetBookmarks(jsonObject);
        return Content(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonResult));
    }

    //Post action for rendering the annotation comments
    public IActionResult RenderAnnotationComments([FromBody] jsonObjects responseData)
    {
        PdfRenderer pdfviewer = new PdfRenderer(_cache);
        var jsonObject = JsonConverterstring(responseData);
        object jsonResult = pdfviewer.GetAnnotationComments(jsonObject);
        return Content(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonResult));
    }

    //Post action for exporting the annotations
    public IActionResult ExportAnnotations([FromBody] jsonObjects responseData)
    {
        PdfRenderer pdfviewer = new PdfRenderer(_cache);
        var jsonObject = JsonConverterstring(responseData);
        string jsonResult = pdfviewer.ExportAnnotation(jsonObject);
        return Content(jsonResult);
    }

    //Post action for importing the annotations
    public IActionResult ImportAnnotations([FromBody] jsonObjects responseData)
    {
        PdfRenderer pdfviewer = new PdfRenderer(_cache);
        var jsonObject = JsonConverterstring(responseData);
        string jsonResult = string.Empty;
        object JsonResult;

        if (jsonObject != null && jsonObject.ContainsKey("fileName"))
        {
            string documentPath = GetDocumentPath(jsonObject["fileName"]);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(documentPath))
            {
                jsonResult = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(documentPath);
            }
            else
            {
                return this.Content(jsonObject["document"] + " is not found");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            string extension = Path.GetExtension(jsonObject["importedData"]);

            if (extension != ".xfdf")
            {
                JsonResult = pdfviewer.ImportAnnotation(jsonObject);
                return Content(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(JsonResult));
            }
            else
            {
                string documentPath = GetDocumentPath(jsonObject["importedData"]);

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(documentPath))
                {
                    byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(documentPath);
                    jsonObject["importedData"] = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
                    JsonResult = pdfviewer.ImportAnnotation(jsonObject);
                    return Content(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(JsonResult));
                }
                else
                {
                    return this.Content(jsonObject["document"] + " is not found");
                }
            }
        }

        return Content(jsonResult);
    }

    //Post action for downloading the PDF documents
    public IActionResult Download([FromBody] jsonObjects responseData)
    {
        PdfRenderer pdfviewer = new PdfRenderer(_cache);
        var jsonObject = JsonConverterstring(responseData);
        string documentBase = pdfviewer.GetDocumentAsBase64(jsonObject);
        return Content(documentBase);
    }

    //Post action for printing the PDF documents
    public IActionResult PrintImages([FromBody] jsonObjects responseData)
    {
        PdfRenderer pdfviewer = new PdfRenderer(_cache);
        var jsonObject = JsonConverterstring(responseData);
        object pageImage = pdfviewer.GetPrintImage(jsonObject);
        return Content(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(pageImage));
    }

    //Gets the path of the PDF document
    private string GetDocumentPath(string document)
    {
        string documentPath = string.Empty;

        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(document))
        {
            string basePath = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath;
            string dataPath = "pdf";
            dataPath = Path.Combine(basePath, dataPath);
            dataPath = Path.Combine(dataPath, document);

            if (System.IO.File.Exists(dataPath))
                documentPath = dataPath;
        }
        else
        {
            documentPath = document;
        }

        return documentPath;
    }
}


Have you asked Syncfusion support? They should know best about how their products work, and what potential problems there are ....
